# C# Windows service with timer not sending data

Tags: c#, mysql, timer, console-application

I made a Windows service that posts performance data to a mySQL database using a json string. However, this service is required to post data every minute. I have added a timer but, it doesn't seem to send the data to the database every minute.

I have 2 classes in my project.
The program class initiates the service and runs the performance code.

```
public static string ServiceName = "performanceService";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new ServiceControl()
        };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        else
        {
            PerformanceCounter ramCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
            PerformanceCounter cpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        }
```

Remaining code is ommitted.

Then I have a ServiceControl class, which in fact is a Windows Service. And in this class I have setup my timer.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
public ServiceControl()
{
    ServiceName = Program.ServiceName;
    InitializeComponent();
}
public void timerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed");
    }

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerElapsed);
    timer.Interval = 60000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();

}
protected override void OnStop()
{
    base.OnStop();
    timer.Enabled = false;
    timer.Stop();
}
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // 
        // ServiceControl
        // 
        this.ServiceName = "performanceService";

    }
```

If there is any additional code that you would like to see, please let me know. 
Is there anything wrong within my code that doesn't allow the service to post the data at the specified interval?
Thank you.

Comment: So what happens? It never posts the data? It posts it once? It posts it at random times? It ...?

Comment: Also, this sounds like it would be a lot easier using a windows service framework with built-in scheduling like [Topshelf.Quartz](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf.Quartz/)

Comment: @stuartd it only posts it when the application is run, rather when the service is running. I would like the service to post info every minute, without running the application.

Comment: @avantvous Try setting  [`Timer.AutoReset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx) Property value to true.

Comment: Is your service working? Is your timer working? Any exceptions...?

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden The status of the service is running. That's the problem, I think my timer is not working, and I do not know why. Any ideas?

Comment: I would add a try catch around your timer and see what happens.

Comment: Do the credentials the service is running under have the required permissions to write to the database? It may be that the timer is firing, but access to the database is denied.

Comment: @stuartd the service is running on LocalSystem if that's what you are asking for.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden I did a try and catch. I got this error: **Unable to copy file "obj\Release\PerfProject.exe" to "bin\Release\PerfProject.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Release\PerfProject.exe' because it is being used by another process.**

Comment: @tchelidze Did not help :(

Comment: Does the `timerElapsed()` need other code or maybe the `Main()` in the program class?

Comment: The "unable to copy" error would be from trying to build the project while the service was running.

Comment: @stuartd Yes, that's exactly what I thought, and I do not get any other error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have placed my timer in the `Main(string[] args)`. This is my answer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 300000; // 30 minutes
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(serverCall);
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Start();
}
```